# How to verify Flutter Bloc added event in widget test?

Tags: flutter, bloc

I have button that when pressed is add a event to bloc like this :

```
ElevatedButton(
  onPressed: () {
    context.read<MyBloc>().add(MyEvent());
  },
  child: ...,
);
```

And then, I want to create a widget test scenario that can verify if bloc adding true event. I created mock class like this :

```
class MockMyBloc extends MockBloc<MyEvent, MyState>
    implements MyBloc {}

class FakeMyEvent extends Fake implements MyEvent {}

class FakeMyState extends Fake implements MyState {}
```

However, when I verify (using [mocktail](https://pub.dev/packages/mocktail)) the addition of the event to the bloc, the result is "No matching calls"

```
verify(() => mockMyBloc.add(MyEvent())); // No matching calls
```

How I can verify bloc is adding true event? Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`verify(() => mockMyBloc.add(MyEvent()));` looks correct.
Double check that you're tapping on the `ElevatedButton` during your test.  Also, make sure that your widget is provided the `MockMyBloc` bloc in your test, and that `MyEvent` extends `Equatable` so that an instance of `MyEvent` is equal to another instance of `MyEvent`.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer! I forgot to add Equatable to bloc event class.